# DialogFragment Transaction Replace

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement a fragment transaction, the following code works but it does not replace the previous dialog fragment. Both dialog fragments appears on the screen. That is not I want.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
AActivity aDifferentDetailsFrag = new AActivity ();
aDifferentDetailsFrag.Show (transaction, "List fragment");
```

Then I have came across the following approach to replace current dialog fragment with the new one, but the code returns an error. I have `AList.axml` where `AActivity` Inflates on.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
AActivity aDifferentDetailsFrag = new AActivity();
transaction.Replace(Resource.Layout.AList, aDifferentDetailsFrag);
transaction.AddToBackStack(null);
transaction.Commit();
```

The following error message:

> No view found for id 0x7f030008 (A.Android:layout/alist) for
>   fragment AActivity{3b61dad8 #2 id=0x7f030008}

I have even changed and tried the following line of code:

```
transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.mAList, aDifferentDetailsFrag);
```

The following error message:

> No view found for id 0x7f07003d (A.Android:id/mAList) for fragment
>   AActivity{29beaca6 #1 id=0x7f07003d}

Here is my `AList.axml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mAList"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Asky"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/aView" />
    <Button
        android:text="Download A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downloadButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is `Resource.Layout.AAList` referring to? Why aren't you using the generated R class to access the Layout container ID?

Comment: I have AList.axml, it is a layout and where AActivity Inflates on.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can do this with your first approach itself

Just call the dismiss method of first dialog that you are showing on the screen before replacing with other dialog fragment.

Let’s  firstDialogFragment be the name so,

```
firstDialogFragment.dismiss();
```

then do this (same as what you suggested)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
AActivity aDifferentDetailsFrag = new AActivity ();
aDifferentDetailsFrag.Show (transaction, "List fragment");
```

**Solution 2:**

This solution is taken from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

```
// DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
// in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
// dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("List_fragment_1");
// assuming previous dialog fragment tag was "list_fragment_1" difficult to do book keeping here "tag"
if (prev != null) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);

// Create and show the dialog.
AActivity aDifferentDetailsFrag = new AActivity ();
aDifferentDetailsFrag.Show (transaction, "List_fragment_2");
```

Comment: `AList.Axml` is a `Layout`. How could you use `Resource.Id.AList` ?

Comment: for example you have layout like  <FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/sample_view
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>  

using id sample_view we can do the replacement ?

Comment: No, it does not work. I am using LinearLayout. Please refer to my updated question.

Comment: AList.xml layout is inflated by your activity rite ? if yes I think you need to have a place holder like framelayout to replace a fragment. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes AList.xml is inflated by my activity. How am I going to do that? Could you please illustrate with an example how could I use placeholder ?

Comment: Hey I have edited my solution hopefully it will help you in some way. Please confirm if it works for you

Comment: FrameLayout that you added in xml?

Comment: Yes I have added that in your AList.xml !

Comment: why did you add FrameLayout?. I am in dialog fragment and when user clicks then I need to move other dialog fragment

Comment: This is just a place holder in your activity , which will be used to give space to fragment. Let's say u have fragment A, then Fragment B and you want to show in you Activity ...so u need this frame layout as a placeholder which will be replaced by your fragment A or B

Comment: Sorry but I think you did not get my question.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry I interpreted in a wrong way, extremely sorry. let me think about a solution and come back to you.

Comment: Hey Texas, I may sound wired here but can't we do with your first approach itself 

just call the dismiss of first dialog that you are showing on the screen 
Let’s  firstDialogFragment be the name so
firstDialogFragment.dismiss();
then do this 
FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
AActivity aDifferentDetailsFrag = new AActivity ();
aDifferentDetailsFrag.Show (transaction, "List fragment");

Comment: That might be temporary solution that could be used. Thanks Dex. I have uprooted your attempt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90643/discussion-between-dex-and-texas).

Comment: Sorry my company intranet does not allow to use chat feature.

Comment: Dude, you rock) I found perfect solution for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Define aDifferentDetailsFrag in a way that you can access it before calling the 2nd DialogFragment and before showing the 2nd DialogFragment .Dismiss() the first